# Codeigniter - update table from form with checkbox

Tags: forms, codeigniter, checkbox, updates, multiple-records

I'm trying to update a `MySQL` table with `Codeigniter`.

My model code is:

```
function update_customer_records($updatedrow)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
    $this->db->update('customers',$updatedrow);
}
```

My view is:

```
    $attributes=array(
        'name'=>'updatecustomer',
        'id'=>'updatecustomer',
        );
    echo form_open('masterdata/manage_customers',$attributes);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Customer Name</td><td>postalcode</td>
    <tr>

<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
<?php echo anchor('masterdata/customers_updated/'.$row->id, img(array('src'=>'images/delete_icon.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'Delete'))); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type=checkbox name="editcustomer[]" id="editcustomer[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->customer_name ; ?>" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->postalcode ; ?>" >
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ; ?>
    </table>
<input type="submit" value="Update Selected">
<?php else : ?>
<h2> No Records Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My controller is :

```
function manage_customers()
    {

        $data['title']="Manage Customers";

            //query model to get data results for form
            $data=array();

            if($query=$this->model_master_data->get_records()){
                $data['records']=$query;


            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_content_master_data_manage_customers",$data);
            $this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");


            $editcustomer = $this->input->post('editcustomer');

            if(isset($editcustomer)){

                //begin outputting id of selected checkbox
                foreach ($editcustomer as $row) :
                    echo $row;

                $updatedrow=array(
                    'id'=>$row,
                    'postalcode'=>'44444'
                    );


                $this->model_master_data->update_customer_records($updatedrow);

                endforeach;
            }
```

**I have two issues :**

1. How do I stop the foreach from running if a checkbox has not been checked.
2. How do I pass the array to the model correctly so that the update runs?

Thanks in advance as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I found two fields in the form with the same name and id (given below) and in one field you are setting it's value `customer_name` and in another you are setting `postalcode`.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->customer_name ; ?>" >
                                --^^--
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="customername_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->postalcode ; ?>" >
                                --^^--
</td>
```

So I think (probably) the name and id of the second field should be `postalcode` according to it's value.

Also you don't need to worry about `foreach` loop because the code inside the loop ll run only if there are checked check boxes on the form because unchecked check boxes won't be submitted but you can check and run the loop using following code

```
if( $this->input->post('editcustomer') != false )
{
    foreach ($editcustomer as $row)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

The `if` condition will return false if the `editcustomer` is not found or not submitted with the form. Also there is no `id` field in your form and in this case you can't use `$this->input->post('id')`, so if you need to check the check box id in the `where clause` of your model then you can use

**In The controller :**

```
if( $this->input->post('editcustomer') != false )
{
    $this->load->model('model_master_data');
    foreach ($editcustomer as $row_id)
    {
        $data = array( 'postalcode' => '44444' );
        $this->model_master_data->update_customer_records( $row_id, $data );
    }
}
```

I don't think you need to pass `'id'=>$row,` because you probably don't wan't to update this field. Also you should use [**form validation**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) to check the form input before updating the record (you may set the postcode field required to bound the user to enter a postcode).

**In The Model :**

```
function update_customer_records( $id, $data )
{
    $this->db->where( 'id', $id );
    $this->db->update( 'customers', $data );
}
```

So it'll do something like this (pseudo code)

```
update the customers table set `postalcode` = '44444' where `id` = $id
```

**Update :**
I think you can also use the [**update_batch**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update).

**In The controller :**

```
if( $this->input->post('editcustomer') != false )
{
    $data = array();
    foreach ($editcustomer as $row_id)
    {
        $data[] = array( 'id' => $row_id, 'postalcode' => '44444';
    }
    $this->load->model('model_master_data');
    $this->model_master_data->update_customer_records( $data );
}
```

**In The Model :**

```
function update_customer_records( $data )
{
    $this->db->update_batch('customers', $data, 'id');
}
```

Comment: Hi Sheikh,  really appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate topic with ["Codeigniter update mysql table from form with CI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176228/codeigniter-update-mysql-table-data-from-form-with-checkbox) ?

> how do I stop the foreach from running if a checkbox has not been checked.

You don't have to stop the foreach from running if a checkbox has not been checked.
Because `$editcustomer` variable only contain checkbox checked.

> How do I pass the array to the model correctly so that the update runs?

Your model is wrong. It should be:

```
public function update_customer_records($updatedrow)
{
    $this->db->update('customers', $updatedrow);
}
```

You don't need to write `$this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));` (and it's wrong, because you can't use $this->input->post() in your model) because you already pass `id` in `$updaterow`.

Edit : I'm sorry, I read your code too quickly!

```
function update_customer_records($updatedrow)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
    $this->db->update('customers',$updatedrow);
}
```

...is correct. Alternatively, you can write it in a shorter way:

```
function update_customer_records($updatedrow)
{
    $this->db->update('customers', $updatedrow, array('id' => $this->input->post('id')));
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell why the `OP` can't use `$this->input->post('id')` in the model ?

Comment: It's (technicaly) possible, but it's not a best practices. Accessing $this->input->post() from the controller is more flexible and it's more in tune with MVC design pattern (in my opinion).

Comment: I asked because you wrote `you can't use ` :-)

Comment: My fault! I should have explain why it's better to don't use directly $this->input->post() in the model, instead of just writing it was not possible.

PS : Sorry for my poor english!